# Turn off reminders for one account in Outlook 2016

Tags: email, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

How do you turn off the reminder notifications in Outlook for one specific account?
I have Outlook 2016 with multiple accounts (some are shared mailboxes) but I don't have to see a popup with all the calendar reminders for all accounts.

I can only find to uncheck the [Default reminders] but that doesn't do what I need.